# Removing symbols and making a tab delimited file while keeping all the words after a certain string in one column

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file full of such lines:

```
>Mouse|chr9:95713136-95716028 | element 1367 | positive  | hindbrain (rhombencephalon)[5/8] | midbrain (mesencephalon)[3/8] | other[7/8]
>Mouse|chr16:90449561-90451327 | element 1672 | positive  | forebrain[4/8] | heart[6/8]
>Mouse|chr3:137446183-137449401 | element 4 | positive  | heart[3/4]
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
 Mouse  chr9    95713136    95716028    element 1367    positive    hindbrain (rhombencephalon)[5/8]|midbrain (mesencephalon)[3/8]|other[7/8]
```

Such that all the words after "positive" are in one column of their own separated by a pipe, and all the columns are separated by tab. 
This is what I did:

```
sed -E 's/ *[>\|:-] */\t/g' mouse_genome_vista1.txt  > mouse_genome_vista2.txt
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i mouse_genome_vista2.txt
```

My output was like this:

```
Mouse   chr9    95713136    95716028    element 1367    positive    hindbrain (rhombencephalon)[5/8]    midbrain (mesencephalon)[3/8]   other[7/8]
Mouse   chr16   90449561    90451327    element 1672    positive    forebrain[4/8]  heart[6/8]
Mouse   chr3    137446183   137449401   element 4   positive    heart[3/4]
```

It works if I have just one word after "positive" it'll be alone in its column . However if I have more than one I'll have multiple columns. For instance hindbrain, midbrain , and other are each in their own tab delimited columns  I want them to be pipe separated in one column.

Comment: where did `chr12` come from? in **What I want to get is something like this:**

Comment: apologies I fixed it, I must have got mixed up due to my large data.

Comment: is positive always in 4th column?

Comment: do you really need to use sed ? sed doesn't support lookahead or look behind but for a one liner solution i think you need something which has positive lookahead capability, say awk  or perl

Answer (score 0):

You may try this with perl or awk:

```
[|:-](?=.*positive)|positive\s+\K\|
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4DfRKG/2/)

[Sample Perl Solution](http://ideone.com/zmlFMf)(note it illustrates over a set of string not file):

```
use strict;

my $str = 'Mouse|chr9:95713136-95716028 | element 1367 | positive  | hindbrain (rhombencephalon)[5/8] | midbrain (mesencephalon)[3/8] | other[7/8]
Mouse|chr16:90449561-90451327 | element 1672 | positive  | forebrain[4/8] | heart[6/8]
Mouse|chr3:137446183-137449401 | element 4 | positive  | heart[3/4]
';
my $regex = qr/[|:-](?=.*positive)|positive\s+\K\|/xmp;
my $subst = '\\t';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;

print $result;
```

Comment: The output I got is this:                                                             `Mouse\tchr9\t95713136\t95716028 \t element 1367 \t positive  \t hindbrain (rhombencephalon)[5/8] | midbrain (mesencephalon)[3/8] | other[7/8]`

Comment: Other lines gave similar output , it worked after positive but before positive as you can see I have \t

Comment: \t is tab character. plz modify it to anything eg "space" to fulfill your need

Comment: if you have tried it in sed, then you should use \t instead of \\t